# Label counter in loop

Tags: graphics, counters, labels

I want to label my figures like this:

```
\label{fig:scatterysX}
```

Where is x a number which changes to some kind of step counter (numeric).
I tried `\newcounter{foo}`, `\stepcounter{foo}` in the loop, and `\value{foo}` on x but this doesn't seem to work.

Please provide a working example.

Comment: Ok thanks for your constructive remark. Luckily Herbert has provided a working example making this a question which could support the broader community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}
\newcounter{foo}\setcounter{foo}{0}
\let\endF\endfigure
\renewcommand\endfigure{%
  \expandafter\label\expandafter{fig:scatterys\thefoo}\endF\stepcounter{foo}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]foo\caption{bar}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[!htb]foo\caption{bar}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[!htb]foo\caption{bar}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[!htb]foo\caption{bar}\end{figure}

see Figure~\vref{fig:scatterys0} or Figure~\vref{fig:scatterys1}
or Figure~\vref{fig:scatterys2} or Figure~\vref{fig:scatterys3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not something special with the `\thefoo` then the `\expandafter` are not really needed.

Comment: Does not really work as expected, the figures are in the appendix. When adding your code i get the output: See Figure Appendix A - on page 5, instead of See Figure 1 on page 5

Comment: Any suggestions on how to let this work..???

Comment: Sigh ... Then simply use `\ref` instead of `\vref` which i used only for the demonstration. And, of course redefine `\thefoo`

Comment: could you tell me how to redefine? not really sure about this

Comment: I need a _complete_ minimal example to see what configuration you are using.

Comment: would this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194957/references-from-auto-generated-images-are-wrong

Comment: using miktex, texlipse, win8, pdflatex

Comment: with `configuration`I meant the settings of your document, eg the documentationclass. YXour link doesn't help it shows no _complete_ example.

Comment: problem solved see above link