# References from auto generated images are wrong

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, automation

In the following I generate labels for some figures that are auto-generated

```
\usepackage{varioref}
\newcounter{figurecounter}\setcounter{figurecounter}{1}
\let\endF\endfigure
\renewcommand\endfigure{%
  \expandafter\label\expandafter{fig:item\thefigurecounter}\endF\stepcounter{figurecounter}}
```

For loop that creates images from folder

```
\newread\reader
\newcount\TotalFiles  


\makeatletter
\newcommand\IterateImages[2]{%
% #1: directory path with a trailing /
% #2: a list of file extensions: eps pdf jpg png
\immediate\write18{batch "#1" \jobname\space #2}
\openin\reader=\jobname.list\relax
\loop
    \read\reader to \filename
    \unless\ifeof\reader
    \filename@parse{\filename}
    %\section*{\filename}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"#1\filename@base"}
    \caption{{\bf This is a figure}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
    \endgraf
    \advance\TotalFiles1\relax
    \clearpage
\repeat
\closein\reader
}
```

Call the for loop in the appendix:

```
\appendix

\gdef\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section} -}
\section{List of figures}
\label{sec:app1}

\IterateImages{C:/Users/xxx/xx}{eps}
```

Now the problem is: when calling `\vref{fig:item1}` it shows:

```
Figure Appendix A - on page 5
```

instead of:

```
Figure 1 on page 5
```

Anyone got an idea how to solve this??????? using miktex, texlipse, win8, pdflatex

When calling

\IterateImages{C:/Users/xxx/xx}{eps}

outside the appendix, figures are numbered correctly

Comment: I can't see where you define the `fig:item1` label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted first code block, and used:

```
\newread\reader
\newcount\TotalFiles  


\makeatletter
\newcommand\IterateImages[2]{%
% #1: directory path with a trailing /
% #2: a list of file extensions: eps pdf jpg png
\immediate\write18{batch "#1" \jobname\space #2}
\openin\reader=\jobname.list\relax
\newcounter{figurecounter}\setcounter{figurecounter}{1}
\loop
    \read\reader to \filename
    \unless\ifeof\reader
    \filename@parse{\filename}
    %\section*{\filename}
    \
    \vfill
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"#1\filename@base"}
    \caption{{\bf text}
    \label{fig:item\thefigurecounter}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
    \vfill
    \
    \stepcounter{figurecounter}
    \endgraf
    \advance\TotalFiles1\relax
    \clearpage
\repeat
\closein\reader
}
```